# How to split lines in .txt file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, text-files

I am trying to format a textfile in MATLAB. For example, a text file looks like this:

```
hello$world
good$morning
thank$you$everybody
```

I would like to split each line when it encounters `$` and write it in the next line. So it should look like this:

```
hello
world
good
morning
thank
you
everybody
```

I am starting to think it has got to do something with `fgetl` and `ischar` but not able to figure it out for .txt file.

How do I split the lines based on `$`?

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at the textscan function in Matlab. You can set the delimeter to $

Answer (score -1):

```
data = importdata('Document.txt'); % Gives cells for every line
fid = fopen('OutputFile.txt','w'); % open an output file
for ii = 1:numel(data) % for each cell
    tmp = strsplit(data{ii},'$'); % split the lines
    for jj = 1:numel(tmp) % for each string found
        fprintf(fid,[tmp{jj},'\r\n']); % write to file with line break
    end
end
fclose(fid); % Close the file
```

You can use [`strplit`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) to split strings based on any desired delimiter.